# Prevent Vscode live server to scroll up on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I write something on stlye.css and save (or wait to live server to refresh), it scrolls my page up...it's really annoying, anyone know how to prevent this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The trick to solve this is to do the following

In program Visual Code:
**File -> Preferences -> settings**

In settings page drop down **Extensions** and click **Live Server Config**

Tick the box:
**Settings:Full Reload**

It stops the change of scroll position that you ask for.

However if it scrolls from top of page (in Chrome at least) down to the scroll position you're on when saving/reloading it is because you use:

```
html {    
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Just comment it out under development (if you have it/use it) and want to prevent that from happening.

**Input from another user:**
Note: you have to stop the live server and start it again to see the changes
(happened to me)

Answer (score 0):

go to live server extension and Disable then enable it ( don't forget to reload window

Answer (score 0):

My issue was fixed by doing the following two step process:

1. Enable the Full Reload in the Live Server extension settings. See if it fixes the problem.
2. Replace the `injected.html` file in the live-server folder which is found in the global `node_module` folder.

   a. To know the global node_module path run the command: npm root -g

   b. Replace the injected.html in your global node_modules live-server folder with [this file](https://gist.github.com/fanfare/edca5a90fa0d5b31eb0980293d9664af).

   c. You may need to `npm cache clear --force` and `npm cache verify` so it recognizes the update.

[How does it work?](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/273#issuecomment-471229763)
The live-server currently first removes the stylesheet from the page (possibly losing the scroll position) then re-adds it. Our process, instead, keeps the old stylesheet in place, then adds the updated version (so there are momentarily 2 versions of the same css file) then kills the old version, so the scroll position never loses focus.

Answer (score -1):

go to vs code setting 1) markdown> Scroll editor with preview --> "off it"
2) markdown> scroll preview with editor --> "off it"