# Prevent VsCode live server to scrolling up

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having an annoying issue with vscode live server. Every single time I hit ctrl+save or even when the files autosaves itself, vscode scroll the page up to the top of it. Sometimes when the page it's big, it just scrolls up to some random point on the page. It happens with every single page I code on Vscode using live server extension.

I tried to reinstall vscode and live server extension. I also found out that some people fixed this ticking "Settings:Full Reload" box. But also didn't work for me.

I just want that when I save the file the browser keeps the same position on the screen. I think code withou a live server feature is really wierd, but this issue is driving me crazy!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Vscode live server to scroll up on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401255/prevent-vscode-live-server-to-scroll-up-on-save)

Answer (score 1):

For me it works "Settings:Full Reload" but remember you have to close server before do that change

Comment: Can you share further details into where to add "Settings: Full Reload"?